# How to feed a command substitution to the "yes" command?

Tags: bash

If I run `yes "I like cheese"` in bash, I will get an endless output of

```
I like cheese
I like cheese
...
...
```

However, I would like to print a random string on each line and thought using `yes` could be a way to get there. So I have tried this command:

```
yes `echo $(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 10)`
```

The problem is it prints the same string over and over because `yes` only takes the first result that

```
`echo $(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 10)`
```

evaluates to, which is a random string (e.g. `d8pTVeZYyi`)

So the result is and endless output of:

```
d8pTVeZYyi
d8pTVeZYyi
d8pTVeZYyi
...
```

How can I make that command substitution run on every line? So that the result is:

```
d8pTVeZYyi
HCmjUpGOIq
K3e8aquaiK
mMJBZYkHJM
...
```

P.S. The overall goal is to be able to generate huge text files with a random string on each line in a reasonable amount of time. Those are needed for test purposes.

Comment: You'd probably be better served by something like `tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -w10`

Comment: @steeldriver This is pretty great. Can you post an answer so I can upvote and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression `echo $(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 10)` is only evaluated once, at the moment when `yes` is laucnhed, so all subsequent iterations just print out the result of that expression.

Some other options:

```
while true; do
    tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 10
    echo ""
done
```

or

```
while true; do
    rand=$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 10)
    echo "$rand"
done
```

Or, better (shamelessly stolen from [@steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321474/how-to-feed-a-command-substitution-to-the-yes-command#comment2251854_1321474)):

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | fold -w10
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first two `while` loops are a much too slow. I want to redirect the output into a file to create big files with random lines of text in them. And the `while` commands are super slow. The `tr` command from you answer doesn't appear to print anything at all. It just hangs there until I Ctrl + C it.

Comment: @codemonkey ah yes, that's because I can't even steal ideas properly! Steeldriver's `fold -w10` was my first thought as well but I wanted to include some other options and stupidly included one that doesn't work. The `grep` will hang because it is waiting for the first end of line character which never arrives. Sorry about that, please see updated answer. And yes, _anything_ involving a shell loop will be very slow.

Comment: Yep. the `tr` solution is what I went with. And since @steeldriver declined to post an answer, I'm accepting this one. Thanks again.